# Python: find most frequent bytes?

Tags: python, byte, frequency

I'm looking for a (preferably simple) way to find and order the most common bytes in a python stream element.

e.g.

```
>>> freq_bytes(b'hello world')
b'lohe wrd'
```

or even

```
>>> freq_bytes(b'hello world')
[108,111,104,101,32,119,114,100]
```

I currently have a function that returns a list in the form `list[97] == occurrences of "a"`. I need that to be sorted.

I figure I basically need to flip the list so `list[a] = b --> list[b] = a` at the same time removing the repeates.

Comment: So, what have you tried? What about it made you unhappy?
We're not here to do all the work for you.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of things. Most of them are really long and tortured, and dont work. I have something that counts the occurrences of the elements, but I can't seem to then order them. That function returns a list where list[97] = occurrences of "a"

Comment: this is what i get for programming at 22:00...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [Counter class](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#counter-objects) in the collections module.

```
from collections import Counter

string = "hello world"
print ''.join(char[0] for char in Counter(string).most_common())
```

Note you need Python 2.7 or later.

Edit: Forgot the most_common() method returned a list of value/count tuples, and used a list comprehension to get just the values.

Comment: I'm on 3.1, so I don't think that's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
def frequent_bytes(aStr):
    d = {}
    for char in aStr:
        d[char] = d.setdefault(char, 0) + 1

    myList = []
    for char, frequency in d.items():
        myList.append((frequency, char))
    myList.sort(reverse=True)

    return ''.join(myList)

>>> frequent_bytes('hello world')
'lowrhed '
```

I just tried something obvious. @kindall's answer rocks, though. :)

Comment: +1 for the effort. note that even if you're not using 2.7+ you can use `collections.defaultdict`

Comment: Aw that's the function I couldn't think of. Thanks!